# Differentiability of multivariable functions represented through integral

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

I have question about differentiability of functions from $\Bbb R^n$ to $\Bbb R$ represented through Lebesgue (Riemann) Integral. Which is somehow generalization of single variable case.

Question 1.
Let $\alpha : \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb (0, +\infty)$ be nice function (for example assume $C^1$), and Let $f : \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ be continuous function   define $$ g(x) = \int_{B(x; \alpha(x))} f(y) ~ dy $$

is $g$ differentiable ? if so what is $\nabla g ?$

If not, what if I fix the center of the Ball  i.e.,

$$ g(x) = \int_{B(a; \alpha(x))} f(y) ~ dy  $$

Obviously  the answer is positive in dimension  one.

Question2. 
Let $f : \Bbb R^n \times \Bbb R^m \to \Bbb R $ be continuous and differentiable w.r.t to first argument,  (you even may assume $f$ is $C^1$ if I didn't make enough assumptions)
Let 
 $$ g(x) = \int_{ \Bbb R^m } f(x,y) ~ dy $$

Is $g$ differentiable ? if so what is $\nabla g ?$

Comment: Why is $g(x)$ even defined in Q. 2?

Comment: @zhw By writing that way I implicitly assumed , $g$ is well defined.

Comment: You assume integrability on f

Answer (score 2):

Question 2 Yes assume f and the partial derivatives D_i(f)  with respect to x are (Lebesgue) integrable in y and | D_i(f) (x,y) | <= G(y)  where G is integrable Then D_i(g) (x) = $\int (D_if(x,y) dy$  (integral is over R^n of course .

Comment: Thanks, can you please write sketch of proof. Or a link to a reference..

Comment: BTW question one easily can be deduced from question 2 if f is differentiable.... I'm interested case where f is just continuous

Comment: i don't know a good reference for question 2 but you just form the difference quotient ,estimate the difference quotient that appears  in the integrand  by a mean value inequality and  apply the bounded convergence theorem from Lebesgue theory , that's where the G is needed . .Sorry  its too involved to do here.

Comment: So your answer is yes, but for a different question (btw, with 700 rep, you should be typesetting the math better)

Answer (score 2):

The answer to Question 2 is no. On $\mathbb R^2$ define

$$f(x,y) = \frac{\sin^2(xy)}{1 +|y|^{3/2}}.$$

Then $f\in C^1(\mathbb R^2)$ and $f(x,y)$ is integrable in $y$ for each $x.$ Define $g$ as you did. Note $g(0)=0.$ Then for $x>0,$

$$\frac{g(x)-g(0)}{x-0} = \frac{1}{x}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin^2(xy)}{1 +|y|^{3/2}}\, dy.$$

Make the change of variables $y = t/x$ to get

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin^2(t)}{x^2 +|x|^{1/2}|t|^{3/2}}\, dy.$$

For $0<x<1,$ we have $x^2 < |x|^{1/2},$ so for such $x$ the last integral is greater than

$$\frac{1}{|x|^{1/2}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin^2(t)}{1+|t|^{3/2}}\, dy.$$

As $x\to 0^+,$ the last expression $\to \infty.$ Thus $g'(0)$ does not exist.

---

**Added later**: For Question 1, we can do the following in the case where the center is fixed. Take $x=0$ for convenience. Then the "polar coordinates" formula for $\mathbb R^n$ shows that if $F(r) = \int_{B(0,r)} f(y)\,dy,$ then

$$F(r) = C_n\int_0^r \int_S f(s\zeta)\, d\sigma(\zeta)\, s^{n-1}\, ds.$$

Here $S$ is the unit sphere, $\sigma$ is normalized surface area measure on $S,$ and $C_n$ is the unnormalized surface area of $S.$ From the FTC, we get

$$F'(r) =C_n r^{n-1}\int_S f(r\zeta)\, d\sigma(\zeta).$$

Let $g(x)=F(\alpha (x)).$ From the above we can say

$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_k}(x) = F'(\alpha (x))\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial x_k}(x) = C_n\alpha(x)^{n-1}\int_S f(\alpha(x)\zeta)\, d\sigma(\zeta)\cdot\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial x_k}(x).$$

If we turn things around, letting the center $x$ move around while the radius remains constant, we get a problem I don't know to solve yet. There's an easy result if $f$ in $C^1.$ But I think you're right to focus on the case where $f$ is only continuous.

Comment: Very nice.  By asking question 2, I wanted to generalize a similar theorem for the case where $f : \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$,  to  case  $f : \Bbb R^n \times \Bbb R^m \to \Bbb R$, So I seems I missed one assumption!   

Do think if we assumed the integral is running on compact set, then we could prove that  using dominated convergence theorem ?, or  assuming $\partial_{x} f$ is Lebesgue integrable?

Comment: @Ashkan  The standard assumption in proving sufficient conditions is that $|\partial f/\partial x_j (x,y) |\le g(y) \in L^1.$ If you knew $f\in C^1$ not just for fixed $y$ but in $(x,y),$ then integrating over a compact set should be just fine, by the result just given.

Comment: I added to my answer.